How does AWS Lambda find and execute the specified handler in a function?
I'm trying to understand how AWS Lambda can find and execute the specified handler in a Lambda function. Specifically, I would like to know:
Handler Resolution Process: How does AWS Lambda use the handler configuration (e.g., MyNamespace.MyClass::MyMethod) to identify and invoke the correct method in a .NET application?
Internal Mechanisms: What are the internal mechanisms or processes that AWS Lambda uses to load the class and execute the specified method in the handler?
Technical Implementation: Is there any documentation or detailed technical explanation about how this "interference" is implemented in the AWS Lambda runtime?
Comparison with Standard Entry Point: How does this approach of specifying a handler externally compare to defining a standard entry point, like the Main method, in terms of execution and flexibility?
I'm looking for technical details about the handler resolution and invocation process in AWS Lambda to better understand how this functionality is implemented and how it might be simulated or adapted in other contexts.

There is an object ILambdaContext provides some very useful information for your invoked function.
